# RubyMotion command line installation

Tags: ios, command-line, installation, continuous-integration, rubymotion

I would like to be able to test my RubyMotion apps on [Circle CI](https://circleci.com).

All of our software is tested, built and deployed with Circle CI, so I thought it would be nice to test my RubyMotion apps on Circle.

There's one problem though: Circle CI lacks support for non-command line installations, which is how RubyMotion must be installed.

I've tried to reverse-engineer the update script, but it keeps returning `404 Not Found`.

Did someone manage to install RubyMotion without GUI? If so, how?

Answer (score -1):

have you checked this?

looks like he did exactly what you are looking for.

https://github.com/mtchavez/circleci-ios

Comment: I am not looking for an app created with RubyMotion, I am looking for a way to test my app on CircleCI.